# I'm trying to automate a process on a website. How do I close a pop up window with selenium, when it is not clear when the popup window will appear?

Tags: python, selenium, web, popup, window

I am trying to close a pop up window with selenium in python, which is not allowing my code to execute further. But I am unable to do that. There is a a pop up window which asks me if i want to sign up but it keeps popping up at inconsistent times. Is there a method to check wether or not the pop-up window is active?

My code so far:

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import time 

    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe";
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH);



    driver.get("https://www.investing.com/news/")
    time.sleep(3)
    accept_cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]');
    accept_cookies.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that you don't want the signup popup to display.

I was just poking the site's script, I found a really nice way for you to work around it: set user agent to `gene`. The script to display popup will be disabled if user agent matches some mobile browsers.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=gene")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/news/")

time.sleep(60) # wait for a minute to see if the popup happens
driver.quit()
```

Run this code, observe the page, it will not display the signup popup.

---

Alternative work around:
Use a Chrome profile that already turned off the Signup popup, will also not display the popup

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
```

---

If you really need to close the popup without these methods, define a check function with try/except. Before doing any actions, call this function to check if there's popup, then close the popup, save the state to some variable (so you don't check it anymore). Since the function has try/except, it will not raise Exception and your code will run.

Comment: The first method with adding the cookie doesn't work for me. It still displays the message. I also can't figure out how the sign up pop-up is activated, it's not time, but I think maybe mouse movement? What I wanted to try was to force the pop-up to happen and then simply close it using the xpath

Comment: First method works for me though, but I've updated another method, to set user agent to `gene`. From my test, it will not display the popup at all. Try and give me a feedback :). Another way to do this is to add ublock extension to your driver, config it so it will block all popup & cookie questions... It will help you to reduce the ads, reduce the load time, easier to automate your script.

Comment: It works now! The only thing I don't get to work is adding a user profile to that chrome browser, but that is not crucial for my code to work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 quick methods that I can think of immediately.

1:

- You will use this often

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

then when you want to get an element that needs time to load and you want to do actions with it, you implement it with WebDriverWait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    accept_cookies = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "'//* 
    [@id=\"onetrust-accept-btn-handler\"]'")))
catch:
    # probably you have a bad locator and the element doesn't exist or it needs more than 10 sec to load.
else:
    # logic here is processed after successfully obtaining the pop up
    accept_cookies.click()
```

2. 

- I would recommend using ActionChains

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

then after you obtain the pop up element make the click like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(accept_cookies).click().perform()
```

This is the equivalent of moving the mouse pointer to the middle of the pop up close btn and clicking it